# Google Maps' stylers doesn't work?

Tags: google-maps

I need to desaturate my google map. I used `stylers` and they doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write('<div id="gmap" style="width:960px; height:360px;"></div>');
                var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(xxx, xxx);
                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("gmap"),  {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: map_center,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    panControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "on" },
                        { saturation: -100 }
                    ]
                });

                var pos;
                var marker;
                for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(xxx, xxx);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Tu jesteśmy',
                        icon: 'pointer.png'
                    });
                }

            </script>
```

Please note that I need to use custom pointers aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [MapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) stylers.  It is styles.

```
            var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("gmap"),  {
                zoom: 11,
                center: map_center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                panControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                styles: [
                {
                   featureType: 'all',
                   elementType: 'all',
                   stylers: [
                     { visibility: "on" },
                     { saturation: -100 }
                  ]
                }]
            });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_styledDynamicMapA.html)

Comment: Did you take out the code to create them?  They won't show on my map as I don't have the local icon (when I comment out that definition, they show up, not sure how useful 10 markers at the same location are...).